# Trying to get property of non-object in (PHP)

Tags: php, json

get error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 11

This is my code:

```
<?php
$json_url = "http://samp-stats.ru/web/api-12492.js";
$json     = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data     = json_decode($json);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($json);
echo "</pre>";


for ($i = 0; $i < count($data->plinfo); $i++) {  
    $document->write($data->plinfo[$i]->name + ' - ' + $data->plinfo[$i]->score + '<br>');    
}


?>
```

Comment: Well, `$document` is never defined in this code... So I'd say "yes, `$document` is _not_ an object".

Comment: That would be a method error though

Comment: I would suggest a var_dump of $data is needed. You are trying to get a property from `$data->plinfo->name` and `->plinfo->score`.  Cannot see if `->plinfo[$i]` is an object

Comment: @Luke Hm, not sure actually, but you might be true. That would leave `$data` not to be an object then which is very well possible if the request to that URL does _not_ produce valid `JSON` which is likely since that URL _appears_ to reference a javascript file...

Comment: Checking that URL, it does *not* produce correct JSON. It shouldn't return `var api = ` at the beginning. Just the JSON

Comment: Albert - Are you going to add a `var_dump($data);` or should we all move on to another question

Comment: Ok did it myself. You are not getting valid json returned. You will have to clean up the string that is returned

Comment: Having identified which line number was 11 would have made this obvious. The error was in your for statement (not the code within the loop). The only 'object' in that line is `$data`, so it was clear that was the issue. In future, if an error has a line number, make it clear in your question what that line is (we can't see all your code, and the question doesn't have line numbers like your IDE does)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is incorrectly formatted.

- There should be nothing preceding the JSON, just the JSON. So remove the `var api =` at the beginning.
- All object names and string values need to be in *double* quotes. So `ip:'37.59.30.67'` needs to read `"ip":"37.59.30.67"`
- No trailing commas at the end of a range, eg. `{name:'Mariu$Bahaos',score:'48' }, ]`. That trailing comma tells the parser to expect another object in the array.
- No semi-colon at the end of your string. `}` is the end character for a JSON string.

Please read up on JSON at [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)

Comment: How can I accomplish this differently in php?

Comment: @albert who is responsible for generating the JSON? Is it you? If so, instead of having http://samp-stats.ru/web/api-12492.js` return the string it does, have it return JSON as described above.

Comment: I not responsible for generating the JSON, 
Thank you anyway!

Comment: @albert If you can contact the person/people who provide the JSON and let them know the above, it might help.